# CSS How to split a div containing a list of divs into 2 columns

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

This Question is a good challenge for you?

I have a div that is filled dynamically in MVC with a list of divs
and I want to have the list split into 2 columns by splitting the list in
half.

The number of divs is not known.

How would you achieve this??

EDIT: When I say split I mean from UI perspective that is all.

Malcolm

Comment: This is a poor question. You could at least have provided some basic demo data. You can use css3 columns for that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts - http://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/

Answer (score 3):

One basic way if you don't mind the columns reading left to right is to just display the child divs as inline-block.

(ps. 49% is due to borders etc., I'm sure there's a better way)

```css
.child {
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">some stuff</div>  
  <div class="child">some stuff</div>  
  <div class="child">some stuff</div>  
  <div class="child">some stuff</div>  
  <div class="child">some stuff</div>  
  <div class="child">some stuff</div>  
  <div class="child">some stuff</div>  
  <div class="child">some stuff</div>  
  <div class="child">some stuff</div>  
  <div class="child">some stuff</div>  
  <div class="child">some stuff</div>  
  <div class="child">some stuff</div>  
  <div class="child">some stuff</div>  
  <div class="child">some stuff</div>  
  <div class="child">some stuff</div>  
  <div class="child">some stuff</div>  
  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use float='Left' to in style in the inside DIV

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inline-block` display property for your child element and make the `width:50%;`

Note: Make sure your `parent div` `font-size` to be `0` which will help you to remove space between your `inline-block` elements.

```
#parent{
    font-size: 0;
}
.child{
    font-size: 16px; 
    display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/66kb11ad/)**